# Turning my code into list comprehensions to allow unlimited data points

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I am creating code that outputs a kernel prediction `ynew`. At first I had this code, which works but only for 3 value datasets:

```
def foobar(data):
    ([a,b,c],[d,e,f]) = data
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]

    #part 1
    kh0 = math.e**(- ((x_new-x[0])**2) / (2*h) )
    kh1 = math.e**(- ((x_new-x[1])**2) / (2*h) )
    kh2 = math.e**(- ((x_new-x[2])**2) / (2*h) )

    #part 2
    w0 = kh0 / (kh0 + kh1 + kh2)
    w1 = kh1 / (kh0 + kh1 + kh2)
    w2 = kh2 / (kh0 + kh1 + kh2)

    #part 3
    ynew = (w0 * y[0]) + (w1 * y[1]) + (w2 * y[2])

    return ynew
```

I need to change my code to allow for unlimited data sets instead of just three. For the labeled part one above I changed it to:

```
k = [math.e**(-(x_new-val)**2 /(2*h)) for val in x]
```

Which is correct. Now I am having trouble changing part 2 and part 3. Here are my attempts for both:

part 2

```
w = [(val / (sum(k))) for val in k]
```

Edit: part 2 now resolved

part 3

```
ynew = sum(w[i] * y[i])
```

My part 3 try isn't correct because I am not sure how to reference it so that it iterates through both the w values and the y values. I am not sure what I am doing wrong for part 2, i followed a similar structure to what I did with part 1 so I don't know what to change.

After one comment now I have part 2 corrected. I am still confused about part 3. My next try is:

```
ynew = (sum(val * y[i]) for val in w)
```

But how can I loop through the values in `w` as well as the values in `y`?

Comment: For part 2 you are trying to subtract a value from a list with `k-val`. It looks like you should only have `val` there. Also the `()` around the entire division and then again around the entire `sum` statement are not needed.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim thank you I didn't notice that!

Comment: Fort part 3: are w and y always the same length? Or are there possibilities of it being different lengths?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim w and y will always be the same length as eachother

Comment: Then you probably want something like `ynew = sum([w[i] * y[i] for i in range(len(w))])`

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a little more safety in it, you can use zip to pull out the values you need. `ynew2 = sum([num1 * num2 for num1, num2 in zip(w,y)])` This is probably better than using `range(len())` but I forgot it when I first commented.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is asking for NumPy:

```
import numpy

x_new = 7
h = 7

data = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [9, 8, 7],
])

x, y = data

kh = np.exp((-(x_new - x) ** 2) / (2 * h))
w = kh / np.sum(kh)
ynew = np.sum(w * y)
```

which allows you to extend your data as you like:

```
data = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 7],
    [9, 8, 7, 9],
])
```